# what does this error mean on my timepicker?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

Does any body know what these errors coming from my error console mean while I am using trent richardson's timepicker? What do I need to do?

$.timepicker is undefined

this line in the jsfile: `$t.datepicker($.timepicker._newInst($t, o)._defaults);`

$.datepicker is undefined

this line in the jsfile: `$.datepicker._base_selectDate = $.datepicker._selectDate;`

trent richardson's jsfile: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

my jsfile has been linked :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<title>Prepare Questions and Answers</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function() {  

$('#answerdurationpicker').timepicker({
        timeFormat:'hh mm ss',
        hourGrid: 4,
        minuteGrid: 10,
        secondGrid: 10,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
        });

        });
```

Comment: Is that **really** the error?  The error message doesn't have a "." in it.

Comment: have you included the necessary `js` files? jquery.js needed to be loaded first and then rest of the plugin files...

Comment: yes jsfiles are loaded into the page, the error message does have a . init I just missed it out, the timepicker works in one file but if I include it in another file with same code, it does not work

Comment: Well then I'd  say there's probably something amiss in your other source file :-)  Is that really the *only* error you get?

Comment: no other error is $.datepicker is undefined which I have now added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to include [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/), which is a separate library from jquery. You should include it right after base jquery. You'll have to download it and modify your code to something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<title>Prepare Questions and Answers</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I forgot to include my <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>, thanks